# google app engine python uploading application first time

Tags: google-app-engine, upload

i'm trying to upload my app engine project for the very first time and i have no clue why it is not working. the error from my terminal is:

```
[me][~/Desktop]$ appcfg.py update ProjectDir/
Application: tacticalagentz; version: 1
Host: appengine.google.com

Starting update of app: tacticalagentz, version: 1
Scanning files on local disk.
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (app_id=u'tacticalagentz').
--- end server output ---
```

i'm using python 2.6.5 and ubuntu 10.04.

not sure if this is relevant, but i just created a google app engine account today. and i also just created the application today (like a couple of hours ago). this is really frustrating because i just want to upload what i have so far (as a demo). in my app.yaml this is my first line:

```
application: tacticalagentz
```

Furthermore, i checked on my admin console, and i CLEARLY see the app id right there, and it matches letter for letter with the app id in my app.yaml

could someone please enlighten me and tell me what i am doing wrong? or is it something beyond my comprehension (like indexing issue with Google that they need time to index my app id) ?

thank you very much in advance

Comment: check your application ID again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apparently adding the "--no_cookies" parameter will work

```
appcfg.py update --no_cookies ProjectDir/
```

the way i was able to find my answer was by uploading my app from my Mac OS X (thank god i have linux mac and windows). AppEngine on Mac OS X comes with a GUI interface, and it worked for uploading. so then i found the command they used in the console, which included "--no_cookies". perhaps if you run into similar issues in the future, this is one approach to getting the answer

Comment: shouldn't you use appcfg.py -A <project-id> update --no_cookies <ProjectDir>/   ? (none of the versions are working for me)

Answer (score 2):

App Engine for Java have the same problem. The problem is about account login.

If you are using Eclipse, use Sign In button.

If u are using command-line, use "-e" option, like this:

```
appcfg.sh -e your@email.com update yoursite/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I changed the name of the app I used in the launcher to match the one in the app engine, It worked without any problem. The way I figured out, it was the name mismatch which caused the problem. You can see the name of your registered app in the admin console of app engine.(https://appengine.google.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what fixed it for me:
i had an instance of dev_appserver.py myProjDirectory/ on a different terminal.

i guess the scripts are somehow linked and aren't thread safe

Answer (score 0):

An alternate option that worked for me is to just "Clear Deployment Credential" from the Control option of the GUI. When the app was deployed after this, it opened a google page to allow GAE to access the user profile and then deployment was successful.

Answer (score -2):

The key bit is

```
This application does not exist (app_id=u'tacticalagentz').
```

which is telling you that appspot.com doesn't know of an application by that name. The admin console (https://appengine.google.com/) shows your applications. Check there. You might have made an inadvertent typo when you registered the app.

Comment: thanks for the response. i quadruple checked to make sure i have no typos or anything. apparently you just have to add the "--no_cookies" parameter when uploading. you can check my answer for more details

Comment: When you see this error it doesn't necessarily mean the application does not exist. It seems to be a catch all for several errors.