# google app engine upload 404

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to upload a simple "hello world" with google app engine (for python).  Every time I do I get the following error

```
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (app_id=u'sqeekytest').
--- end server output ---
```

I've checked and double checked that the app_id matches.  I found a possible solution in the following thread however I am a complete noob at this and I'm not sure that I am doing this correctly.

[This application does not exist (app_id=xxx)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7039200/3761017)

It seems that the most common solution to this problem is to run appcfg.py update . --no_cookies.  What I don't know is where I am running it.  Is it in cmd, the python shell, the google cloud SDK shell that comes with the program?  I've tried it a few different places and the only result I have gotten is the launching of pycharm.  Either the solution is not working for me or I am doing something dumb (more likely).  I cannot figure this out.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [google app engine python uploading application first time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624629/google-app-engine-python-uploading-application-first-time)

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal or command prompt and cd to the directory of your project

```
$ cd path/to/project
```

Then from there do

```
$ appcfg.py update . --no_cookies
```

That assumes your `app.yaml` is in the root directory of your project. If it's in a different directory, specify it by

```
$ appcfg.py update /path/to/directory/where/app.yaml/is --no_cookies
```

It could be that `appcfg.py` is not in your PATH, in that case you could add it to the PATH or simply specify the location, also from within the root directory of your project.

```
$ path/to/google-cloud-sdk/bin/appcfg.py update . --no_cookies
```

This will open a webpage in a browser asking for permission and once you have given it it will automatically continue with the deploying process in the terminal/command prompt.